# generate a matrix with numbers between [0,1]

Tags: matlab

I have to generate a matrix of n x n uniformly distributed random numbers (n read from keyboard). The numbers should be between [0,1] and then to average the numbers > 0.5. I've tried the following:

```
value = 'Insert a value for n: ';
x = input(value);

matrix = rand(x,x);

matrix2(matrix < 0.5) = nan;

average = mean(matrix2, 'omitnan');
disp(average);
```

After I run the code I get that average is 0 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the line `matrix2(matrix < 0.5) = nan;` is the first time you mention `matrix2`, so this actually *creates* the `matrix2`. This "creation" indexing syntax ends up creating `matrix2` with the same size as `matrix`, filling the elements where `matrix < 0.5` with `nan`, and it will actually leave the other elements as `0`.

What you want is to start out with `matrix2` as a *copy* of `matrix`, and then set the elements, in other words

```
matrix2 = matrix;
matrix2(matrix2 < 0.5) = nan;
```

Comment: `matrix2 = matrix;` does not *copy* the matrix. Both variables will point to the same object in memory. Changing `matrix2` will also influence the original `matrix`.

Comment: @Green绿色 _"Changing `matrix2` will also influence the original `matrix`"_ - this is wrong, in MATLAB they would be independent, changing one would not change the other

Comment: I see. Sorry, I didn't read carefully and assumed, this is a `numpy` question.